# Can any one help me to solve the following definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Here is my integral 
>   $$\int_0^a \dfrac{x\sin(bx)e^{-2cx}(1+cx)^2}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dx$$

I know that you will look for my work, but frankly speaking, I have no idea where from I should have to start. It totally confused me a lot. Please shed light on my problem and solve it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is from Maple.  Perhaps this is useless to you.

$$
\int_{0}^{a}\!{\frac {x\sin \left( bx \right) {{\rm e}^{-2\,cx}}
 \left( cx+1 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( {a}^{2}+{x}^{2} \right) ^{2}}}
\,{\rm d}x=\\
\frac{-1}{8a^2}\Bigg({i{{\rm e}^{-iab-2\,ac}}-i{{\rm e}^{iab-2\,ac}
}+2\,{{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic-b+ib+2\,c
 \right)  \right) {a}^{2}bc+2\,{{\rm e}^{-a \left( 2\,ic+b \right) }}{
\rm Ei}_1 \left(-a \left( 2\,ic+b \right)  \right) {a}^{3}{c}^{3}-2\,
{{\rm e}^{-2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a \left( -2\,c+ib+2\,ic+b
 \right)  \right) {a}^{3}{c}^{3}+2\,{{\rm e}^{2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(-a \left( -2\,ic-b-2\,c+ib \right)  \right) {a}^{3}{c}^{3}+2
\,{{\rm e}^{-2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( -2\,ic+b+ib+2\,c
 \right)  \right) {a}^{3}{c}^{3}-2\,{{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(a \left( 2\,ic-b+ib+2\,c \right)  \right) {a}^{3}{c}^{3}+2\,
{{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic-b \right) 
 \right) {a}^{3}{c}^{3}-2\,{{\rm e}^{-2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a
 \left( 2\,ic-b \right)  \right) {a}^{3}{c}^{3}-2\,{{\rm e}^{a \left( 
2\,ic+b \right) }}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic+b \right)  \right) 
{a}^{3}{c}^{3}-2\,{{\rm e}^{a \left( 2\,ic+b \right) }}{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(a \left( 2\,ic+b \right)  \right) {a}^{2}bc-2\,{{\rm e}^{-a
 \left( 2\,ic+b \right) }}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a \left( 2\,ic+b \right) 
 \right) {a}^{2}bc-2\,{{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 
2\,ic-b \right)  \right) {a}^{2}bc-2\,{{\rm e}^{-2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(-a \left( 2\,ic-b \right)  \right) {a}^{2}bc+2\,{{\rm e}^{-2
\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a \left( -2\,c+ib+2\,ic+b \right) 
 \right) {a}^{2}bc+2\,{{\rm e}^{2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a
 \left( -2\,ic-b-2\,c+ib \right)  \right) {a}^{2}bc+2\,{{\rm e}^{-2\,i
ac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( -2\,ic+b+ib+2\,c \right)  \right) {a
}^{2}bc-i{{\rm e}^{-a \left( 2\,ic+b \right) }}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a
 \left( 2\,ic+b \right)  \right) {a}^{3}b{c}^{2}+i{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a
 \left( -2\,ic+b+ib+2\,c \right)  \right) {{\rm e}^{-2\,iac+ab}}{a}^{3
}b{c}^{2}+i{{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic-b
 \right)  \right) {a}^{3}b{c}^{2}-i{{\rm e}^{2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(-a \left( -2\,ic-b-2\,c+ib \right)  \right) {a}^{3}b{c}^{2}-
i{{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic-b+ib+2\,c
 \right)  \right) {a}^{3}b{c}^{2}-i{{\rm e}^{-2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(-a \left( 2\,ic-b \right)  \right) {a}^{3}b{c}^{2}+i{{\rm e}
^{a \left( 2\,ic+b \right) }}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic+b
 \right)  \right) {a}^{3}b{c}^{2}+i{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a \left( -2\,c+i
b+2\,ic+b \right)  \right) {{\rm e}^{-2\,iac-ab}}{a}^{3}b{c}^{2}-2\,i{
{\rm e}^{a \left( 2\,ic+b \right) }}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic+b
 \right)  \right) {a}^{2}{c}^{2}-i{{\rm e}^{a \left( 2\,ic+b \right) }
}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic+b \right)  \right) ab+i{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(-a \left( 2\,ic+b \right)  \right) {{\rm e}^{-a \left( 2\,ic
+b \right) }}ab-2\,i{{\rm e}^{-a \left( 2\,ic+b \right) }}{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(-a \left( 2\,ic+b \right)  \right) {a}^{2}{c}^{2}+i{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(-a \left( -2\,ic-b-2\,c+ib \right)  \right) {{\rm e}^{2\,iac
+ab}}ab+i{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic-b+ib+2\,c \right)  \right) {
{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}ab+i{{\rm e}^{-2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a
 \left( 2\,ic-b \right)  \right) ab+2\,i{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a \left( -2
\,c+ib+2\,ic+b \right)  \right) {{\rm e}^{-2\,iac-ab}}{a}^{2}{c}^{2}-2
\,i{{\rm e}^{-2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( -2\,ic+b+ib+2\,c
 \right)  \right) {a}^{2}{c}^{2}+2\,i{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a \left( -2\,i
c-b-2\,c+ib \right)  \right) {{\rm e}^{2\,iac+ab}}{a}^{2}{c}^{2}-2\,i{
{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic-b+ib+2\,c
 \right)  \right) {a}^{2}{c}^{2}+2\,i{{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1
 \left(a \left( 2\,ic-b \right)  \right) {a}^{2}{c}^{2}+2\,i{
{\rm e}^{-2\,iac+ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a \left( 2\,ic-b \right) 
 \right) {a}^{2}{c}^{2}-i{{\rm e}^{-2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( -a
 \left( -2\,c+ib+2\,ic+b \right)  \right) ab-i{{\rm e}^{-2\,iac+ab}}{
\rm Ei}_1 \left(a \left( -2\,ic+b+ib+2\,c \right)  \right) ab-i{
{\rm e}^{2\,iac-ab}}{\rm Ei}_1 \left( a \left( 2\,ic-b \right) 
 \right) ab+i{{\rm e}^{iab-2\,ac}}{a}^{2}{c}^{2}-i{{\rm e}^{-iab-2\,ac
}}{a}^{2}{c}^{2}-2\,i{{\rm e}^{iab-2\,ac}}ac+2\,i{{\rm e}^{-iab-2\,ac}
}ac} \Bigg)
$$

---

machine-readable:

`Int(x*sin(b*x)*exp(-2*c*x)*(c*x+1)^2/(a^2+x^2)^2,x = 0 .. a) = -1/8*(I*exp(-I*a
*b-2*a*c)-I*exp(I*a*b-2*a*c)+2*exp(2*I*a*c-a*b)*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c-b+I*b+2*c))*a^2*b
*c+2*exp(-a*(2*I*c+b))*Ei(1,-a*(2*I*c+b))*a^3*c^3-2*exp(-2*I*a*c-a*b)*Ei(1,-a*(
-2*c+I*b+2*I*c+b))*a^3*c^3+2*exp(2*I*a*c+a*b)*Ei(1,-a*(-2*I*c-b-2*c+I*b))*a^3*c
^3+2*exp(-2*I*a*c+a*b)*Ei(1,a*(-2*I*c+b+I*b+2*c))*a^3*c^3-2*exp(2*I*a*c-a*b)*Ei
(1,a*(2*I*c-b+I*b+2*c))*a^3*c^3+2*exp(2*I*a*c-a*b)*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c-b))*a^3*c^3-2*
exp(-2*I*a*c+a*b)*Ei(1,-a*(2*I*c-b))*a^3*c^3-2*exp(a*(2*I*c+b))*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c+b
))*a^3*c^3-2*exp(a*(2*I*c+b))*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c+b))*a^2*b*c-2*exp(-a*(2*I*c+b))*Ei(
1,-a*(2*I*c+b))*a^2*b*c-2*exp(2*I*a*c-a*b)*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c-b))*a^2*b*c-2*exp(-2*I
*a*c+a*b)*Ei(1,-a*(2*I*c-b))*a^2*b*c+2*exp(-2*I*a*c-a*b)*Ei(1,-a*(-2*c+I*b+2*I*
c+b))*a^2*b*c+2*exp(2*I*a*c+a*b)*Ei(1,-a*(-2*I*c-b-2*c+I*b))*a^2*b*c+2*exp(-2*I
*a*c+a*b)*Ei(1,a*(-2*I*c+b+I*b+2*c))*a^2*b*c-I*Ei(1,-a*(2*I*c+b))*exp(-a*(2*I*c
+b))*a^3*b*c^2+I*Ei(1,a*(-2*I*c+b+I*b+2*c))*exp(-2*I*a*c+a*b)*a^3*b*c^2+I*exp(2
*I*a*c-a*b)*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c-b))*a^3*b*c^2-I*Ei(1,-a*(-2*I*c-b-2*c+I*b))*exp(2*I*a
*c+a*b)*a^3*b*c^2-I*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c-b+I*b+2*c))*exp(2*I*a*c-a*b)*a^3*b*c^2-I*exp(
-2*I*a*c+a*b)*Ei(1,-a*(2*I*c-b))*a^3*b*c^2+I*exp(a*(2*I*c+b))*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c+b))
*a^3*b*c^2+I*Ei(1,-a*(-2*c+I*b+2*I*c+b))*exp(-2*I*a*c-a*b)*a^3*b*c^2-2*I*exp(a*
(2*I*c+b))*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c+b))*a^2*c^2-I*exp(a*(2*I*c+b))*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c+b))*a*b+I
*Ei(1,-a*(2*I*c+b))*exp(-a*(2*I*c+b))*a*b-2*I*Ei(1,-a*(2*I*c+b))*exp(-a*(2*I*c+
b))*a^2*c^2+I*Ei(1,-a*(-2*I*c-b-2*c+I*b))*exp(2*I*a*c+a*b)*a*b+I*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c-
b+I*b+2*c))*exp(2*I*a*c-a*b)*a*b+I*exp(-2*I*a*c+a*b)*Ei(1,-a*(2*I*c-b))*a*b+2*I
*Ei(1,-a*(-2*c+I*b+2*I*c+b))*exp(-2*I*a*c-a*b)*a^2*c^2-2*I*Ei(1,a*(-2*I*c+b+I*b
+2*c))*exp(-2*I*a*c+a*b)*a^2*c^2+2*I*Ei(1,-a*(-2*I*c-b-2*c+I*b))*exp(2*I*a*c+a*
b)*a^2*c^2-2*I*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c-b+I*b+2*c))*exp(2*I*a*c-a*b)*a^2*c^2+2*I*exp(2*I*a
*c-a*b)*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c-b))*a^2*c^2+2*I*exp(-2*I*a*c+a*b)*Ei(1,-a*(2*I*c-b))*a^2*
c^2-I*Ei(1,-a*(-2*c+I*b+2*I*c+b))*exp(-2*I*a*c-a*b)*a*b-I*Ei(1,a*(-2*I*c+b+I*b+
2*c))*exp(-2*I*a*c+a*b)*a*b-I*exp(2*I*a*c-a*b)*Ei(1,a*(2*I*c-b))*a*b+I*exp(I*a*
b-2*a*c)*a^2*c^2-I*exp(-I*a*b-2*a*c)*a^2*c^2-2*I*exp(I*a*b-2*a*c)*a*c+2*I*exp(-
I*a*b-2*a*c)*a*c)/a^2`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am also want the complete solution with steps.

Comment: Would you please ?